# I'm trying to learn about Regular Expressions

Tags: java, pattern-matching, metacharacters

1.Based on this code https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/regex/test_harness.html

Can anyone please explain what is this **`\"%s\"`** in

```
while (matcher.find()) {
        console.format("I found the text" + " \"%s\" starting at " +
        "index %d and ending at index %d.%n",
        matcher.group(),
        matcher.start(),
        matcher.end());
        found = true;
}
```

I just know that `%s` is for string.

2.Refering the meta-characters https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/regex/literals.html is there any explanation for this outputs?

[image]

Comment: `%s` a formatter character and serves the purpose of format-based printing, which has nothing to do with regular expressions per se. API [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Formatter.html).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`\"%s\"` mean you want to put a String between two quotes for example the result can be :

```
I found the text "some string"
//""-------------^           ^
// %s             ^_________^
```

`%s` use for Strings, if you want to use digit you can use `%d` and so on

In Java quote should be escaped **how?** you can use backslash `\"` so consider I have a String which contain quotes like this `Hello "World"` how to use this as a String in Java :

```
String string = "Hello "World"";  //<<------- this is an error syntax
```

To solve it, you have to escape the quotes :

```
String string = "Hello \"World\"";
                       ^      ^
```

take a look at https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Formatter.html

Comment: what are the two back slashes for?

Comment: They escape the quotes (`"`). You can remove them and you'll see what error you get.

Comment: @Jérôme you will get `java.lang.RuntimeException: Uncompilable source code - not a statement`

Comment: Thank you so much @YCF_L Can you suggest me some sites from where I can learn specific topics?

Answer (score 1):

The percentage sign (`%`) in a `String` in combination with the letters b, c, d, e, f, s, is used to limit the number of characters to display.

`%b`- booleans
`%c`- character
`%d`- integer
`%e`- scientific notation
`%f`- floating point number (double, float)
`%s`- String

For example:

```
String text = "abcdef";
System.out.printf("%.3s", text); //output:  abc
```

or

```
String text = "\"abcdef\"";
System.out.printf("%.3s", text); //output:  "ab
```

Comment: btw it is "%.3s"  . Anyways Thanks.